# Open MdiForm from Usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MainForm, ChildForm and usercontrol1. I embed usercontrol1 to Mainform. And there is a button in usercontrol1. I want to open ChildForm(as a mdiform) when clicked to button. ChildForm has opened maximized. I want to always show MainForm Titlebar.
here code i tried, but its not working. this code in usercontrol1's button click event

```
ChildForm t = new ChildForm ();

            MainForm m = new MainForm();
            t.MdiParent = m; //Also I tried 'this' too
            t.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            t.Show();
```

thank you

Comment: Don't create a *new* main form of course, you want to use the existing one.  If you can't get the reference to it at all then Application.OpenForms[0] would be hack to get it.  In general, user controls should not be in the business of create new windows by themselves.  They should raise an event instead.  Of course the parent has no trouble subscribing the event and getting a reference to the main window.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I agree with you that a UC shouldn't create a new form. I've seen where a `UserControl` (inheriting from `Button`) was developed to encapsulate the process of reflectively loading `Form` controls (or creating a `Form` and adding a `UserControl` to it if the provided object didn't inherit from `Form`), saving a lot of time re-writing the same code in the `Click` event.

Comment: So you've seen bad code before, that doesn't prove anything.  If it is so superior then of course exposing a public method is a simple way to allow the parent to reuse that code in its event handler.  Or not and do its own thing, the point of events.

Answer (score 0):

In your `MainForm`, create a [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) and then your code would look like this:
MainForm Code:

```
private static MainForm _Instance;
public static MainForm Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
        {
            _Instance = new MainForm();
        }
        return _Instance;
    }
}
```

Event Code:

```
ChildForm t = new ChildForm();
t.MdiParent = MainForm.Instance; 
t.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
t.Show();
```

Comment: I've added an example of the singleton I used, can you compare (this is working in VS2013 with .Net 4.0).

Comment: I got error ; "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveForm` to get the current MDIForm Actived:

```
ChildForm t = new ChildForm ();
MainForm m = new MainForm();
t.MdiParent = m.ActiveForm;
t.Show();
```